# Query DSL & Maven: Classes not generated, but only on command line (in eclipse it is working fine)

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

We are using a setup with Spring Boot, Hibernate, Query DSL and Maven with Java 1.8

Recently, I've added Query DSL to the project with the configuration listed below. To make it work, I had to configure the Java Compiler in the eclipse project settings to allow Annotation Processing and also add the Query DSL `.jar` file to the eclipse Annotation Factory Path.

This setup worked as expected. It generated the custom `Q` classes and I could use them in my code. When now running the `mvn clean install` on the command line, every class in my code throws the error `cannot find symbol`, because the class is missing. Is there anything else I need to configure - similar to the `.jar` file in the eclipse settings - to make the build process work?

**EDIT:** This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) because I did not ask why this error (cannot find a symbol) occurs but rather how to configure QueryDSL to also work on the command line.

**EDIT2:** I have now tried to integrate the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to use multiple source paths as an input. This did not help either. I also tried to generate the files into a `src` folder. It did not help either.

When I first compile the library in eclipse, the `mvn compile` goes through on the command line, but `mvn clean compile` still fails, because it just uses the compiled files of eclipse again. The apt-maven-plugin is executed, which can be seen just before the build process fails:

```
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ project1 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (add-source) @ project1 ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Users\user1\git\project1\src\main\generated added.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ project1 ---
[ERROR] diagnostic: [...]
```

**EDIT3:** When I remove every import statement which is referring to the `Q` classes, the build process goes through (obviously). It is, however, remarkable, that the `Q` classes get compiled correctly in that case. They appear in the `target` folder as `.class` files as they should. Could it be, that the `Q` classes are compiled too late?

---

**Here is an excerpt of the `pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    [...]
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        [...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            [...]
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        [...]
    </build>
</project>
```

**This is the configuration of the eclipse project settings:**

[image]

**This is the error message which is displayed in the console:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ project1 ---
[ERROR] diagnostic: C:\Users\user1\git\project1\src\main\java\com\project1\repository\UserRepositoryImpl.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import static com.project1.domain.QUser.user;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class QUser
  location: package com.project1.domain

[ERROR] diagnostic: C:\Users\user1\git\project1\src\main\java\com\project1\repository\UserRepositoryImpl.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static com.project.domain.QUser.user;
^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: As I've written above, it is perfectly clear why this error occurs. The generated class is not there, because it is not generated correctly while running `mvn compile` on the command line. It is then imported and obviously not found. The answer, however, should resolve this underlying problem and not go into details about this error. Therefore, not a duplicate @feelingunwelcome

Answer (score 4):

For me, it didn't work because it conflicted with maven-compiler-plugin with already set annotation processor. Just deleted the use of apt-maven-plugin and added its annotation processor in maven-compiler-plugin.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            related to issues:-->
<!--                - https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2654 -->
<!--                - https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2242 -->
<!--            Using apt-maven-plugin conflicts with other annotation processors (like mapStruct) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>5.0.0</version>
                            <classifier>jpa</classifier>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.3</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.2</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>1.1.3</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>process</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                        <configuration>-->
<!--                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>-->
<!--                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>-->
<!--                        </configuration>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But there is an [issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2242) with using querydsl annotation processor in maven-compiler-plugin. You have to add jakarta.persistence-api and javax.annotation-api.

Answer (score 3):

This is old question but this is how i find my solution, added classifier for jpa dependency:

```
    <!-- BEGIN: 'querydsl-jpa' -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl-jpa.version}</version>
        <classifier>apt</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: 'querydsl-jpa' -->
```

My complete pom:

```
<!-- BEGIN: BUILD -->
<build>

    <!-- BEGIN: PLUGINS -->
    <plugins>

        <!-- BEGIN: apt-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END: apt-maven-plugin -->

    </plugins>
    <!-- END: PLUGINS -->

</build>
<!-- END: BUILD -->

<!-- BEGIN: DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>

    <!-- *********************************************** -->
    <!-- BEGIN: 'QUERYDSL DEPENDENCIES'                  -->

    <!-- BEGIN: 'querydsl-apt' -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: 'querydsl-apt' -->

    <!-- BEGIN: 'querydsl-jpa' -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl-jpa.version}</version>
        <classifier>apt</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END: 'querydsl-jpa' -->

    <!-- *********************************************** -->
    <!-- END: 'QUERYDSL DEPENDENCIES'                    -->


</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use profile to generate these Qclasses only when db change occurs.

cons:

-your diff in pull requests is clean when you don't change db schema because for each generation these files tend to generate differently for some reason (atleast in my case).

-you can manage witch of tables present in your db will have Qclasses (sometimes it is a pain when you forget to regenerate them after changing db schema)

-well not that it is lots of time . but builds are faster if You don't change schema and profile is turned off.

Try something like this and turn on profile when You want to generate changed schema Qclasses :

```
<properties>
    <whitelisted.tables>
        user_accunt,
        other
    </whitelisted.tables>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>generate</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>export</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <jdbcDriver>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbcDriver>
                        <jdbcUrl>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/dbname</jdbcUrl>
                        <packageName>your.package.name.for.q</packageName>
                        <jdbcUser>dbusername</jdbcUser>
                        <jdbcPassword>dbpassword</jdbcPassword>
                        <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</targetFolder>
                        <spatial>true</spatial>
                        <tableNamePattern>${whitelisted.tables}</tableNamePattern>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                            <version>42.1.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I would rather like to generate those files directly during the build. I have also several DTO Q classes which need to be generated, so it is not only required on a database change. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there a way to run a mvn script to just generate the Q classes e.g. into `src/main/generated` and then afterwards use this folder as a second source folder in a regular maven build?

Comment: provided MVN configuration allows You to use these classes in project. 
also You may always create different module to add dependency to another module/modules. I can imagine that is what You want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The generated-source directory are not automatically included in the jar.

You need to use the Maven build helper plugin to fix this issue, for example:

https://github.com/alexec/javahelp-skeleton/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that, without any success. The source is added (according to the maven logs) but the same error occurrs..

Answer (score 0):

You can try out few things:
1.try to put `<clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>` in your `configuration` tag
 
2. Sometimes classes might not be getting generated before the compile phase. So try to put phase in your plugin

```
   <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>...</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

By convention Maven assumes all source code is in 'src/main/java', compiles this and put all *.class file in target.

So if you have a class '`Alien.java`' in `<project-root>/alice/in/wonderland`, your won't be able to access it (in src/main/java) because maven puts everything from `src/main/java` in classpath for your compiler and hence compiler is unaware of any source code (*.java) anywhere else.

In your case you are generating your source code in directory `target/generated-sources/java`, so you will have to tell maven about it. As mentioned in some other answers you may use build-helper-plugin for this, let maven know that your source resides on `target/generated-sources/java` by

```
 <project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>target/generated-sources/java</source>
                <source>alice/in/wonderland</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Edit: You have mentioned wrong path in build-helper-plugin**

I see although you are using build helper plugin but you are using wrong path

```
 --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (add-source) @ project1 ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Users\user1\git\project1\src\main\generated added.
```

Instead of `src\main\generated` you should use `<source>target/generated-sources/java</source>`

Comment: I've played around with this plugin, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. The output says, that the additional path was added, but it still fails to compile.

Comment: I've also tested multiple paths, therefore `src/main/generated` and `target/generated-sources/java`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 can you give the complete stacktrace of maven?